# How to make GroupBy Table return only One value in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Hi so I have 2 Table with one to many Relationship, I use ado net and Join query to get the Table and the referenced one, after that I cast my DataTable as Enumerable and then use the Linq operation to return it as nested JSON. But the problem is only the GroupBy field will return one data using the key and every else will return an array as many as the record have like this

```
  {
        "id": 23,
        "date": [
            "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-01-01T00:00:00"
        ],
        "total_room_sold": [
            41,
            41,
            41,
            41
        ],
        "total_rom_revenue": [
            19340082,
            19340082,
            19340082,
            19340082
        ],
        "Segment": {
            "segment_name": [
                "BFR",
                "DIS",
                "PAR",
                "LON"
            ],
            "room_sold": [
                4,
                2,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "revenue_by_segment": [
                1904628,
                686605,
                461157,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
```

And for the N:1 Table do I need to GroupBy again so I can get like this for the segment

```
  {
            "id": 23,
            "date": [
                "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
                "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
                "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
                "2018-01-01T00:00:00"
            ],
            "total_room_sold": [
                41,
                41,
                41,
                41
            ],
            "total_rom_revenue": [
                19340082,
                19340082,
                19340082,
                19340082
            ],
            "Segment": [
             {
              "segment_name": "BFR",
              "rooom_sold" : 4,
              "revenue_by_segment" : 412313213
             },
             {
              "segment_name": "BFR",
              "rooom_sold" : 2,
              "revenue_by_segment" : 12312313
             }
             ]  

        }
```

My code for now

```
var dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<dynamic>(id)).Select(x => new {
 id = x.key,
 date = x.Field<dynamic>("date"),
 total_room_sold = x.Field<dynami>(total_room_sold),
 Segment = x.Select(s => new {
 segment_name = s.Field<dynamic>("segment_name"),
 room_sold = s.Field<dynamic>("room_sold"),
 })

})
```

Comment: Your code has no `GroupBy` in it, so it doesn't seem relevant to the question (or vice-versa)? We don't know what the "GroupBy field" is unless you tell us, and so on. Also, using `dynamic` is an extremely bad idea unless you know what you are doing. It is essentially never the right choice.

Comment: But to answer your title question, you must go back to what does `GroupBy` do? It partitions a set of data into groups (i.e. multiples) of entities that are somehow related. Given a group of entities, how do you convert to a single entity? By using a choice method or aggregate method to either pick one (e.g. `First`, `Last`, `Max`, `Min`) or combine them all (e.g. `Sum`,`Average`) to get a single result.

Comment: @NetMage ups sorry this is actually only snippets for my actual code, I forget to add the GroupBy. I have 2 Table OTB and Segment, I want GroupBy Segment Table by OTB, why I use dynamic because I want to create dynamic API that will work not only for Segment and OTB but any 1: N Table, this is not the real code just the outline of my code

Comment: @NetMage hmm maybe I can use FirstorDefault In my 1: N Table, Is it will return One record every GroupBy or One record of my Table? Thanks

Comment: You could just use `First`, as a `GroupBy` can't create empty groups. Depending on where you put the `First`, you would get either the first group, or the first row of each group. If you put `First` in your `Select`, it will be the first row of each group.

Comment: BTW, as far as `dynamic`, you should be able to use generic methods instead, just like LINQ, that works with any type, unless you are also passing `dynamic` data in.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks for your answer It works using First in my Select Field, How about my N: 1 Table why its return like that? I tried to add ToList in my Segment Select It Does return an array of my Record, but it returns all value from GroupBy, in every column

Comment: It is hard to follow since you don't provide (an example of) the source table `dt`, but you have the same problem. Consider naming your lambda parameters (query range variables) something more useful than x - e.g. in your `GroupBy` use `r`, then in your `Select` use `rg` and it will help you remember that `rg` is _multiple rows_, and you must deal with that.